# DataBricks - json string in column to multiple columns

Tags: python, dataset, data-cleaning

newbie question :
I've got a Data Frame with column containing Json string.

Question:
how do i extract the data in one column to multiple column by key value.

here is the data (dummy data):

```
{"Gcid":13889192,"CountryCode":"196","SubProgram":"IBAN EU Green","Program":"Iban","Region":"Europe","AccountId":"c6884917-179f-4076-bd91-f81fbc8bcd8f","CurrencyBalanceId":"7fd5d124-5e8b-4ea8-8911-6d57dffd304f","BankAccountId":"5d0fcdca-5517-4175-a935-bea88b04f7b7","CorrelationId":"ceacb665-63e6-4dde-a830-9a3d6a820dda","Created":"2023-04-30T13:37:50.0182147Z"}
```

in column EventPayload
[image]

I want to extract the data to multiple column to one DataFrame
so that the result will be **for all columns**

[image]

tried so far :

```
EventPayloadSchema = ['Gcid','CountryCode','SubProgram','Program','Region','AccountId','CurrencyBalanceId','BankAccountId','CorrelationId','Created']
```

```
df_filtered.withColumn("EventPayload", from_json("EventPayload", schema))\
    .select(col('Gcid'), col('CountryCode'), col('SubProgram'), col('Program'), col('Region'), col('AccountId'), col('CurrencyBalanceId'),col('BankAccountId'),col('CorrelationId'),
        col('Created'))\
    .show()
```

Results :

```
AnalysisException: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `Gcid` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`EventPayload`];
'Project ['Gcid, 'CountryCode, 'SubProgram, 'Program, 'Region, 'AccountId, 'CurrencyBalanceId, 'BankAccountId, 'CorrelationId, 'Created]
+- Project [from_json(StructField(Gcid,StringType,true), StructField(CountryCode,StringType,true), StructField(SubProgram,StringType,true), StructField(Program,StringType,true), StructField(Region,StringType,true), StructField(AccountId,StringType,true), StructField(CurrencyBalanceId,StringType,true), StructField(BankAccountId,StringType,true), StructField(CorrelationId,StringType,true), StructField(Created,StringType,true), EventPayload#13, Some(Etc/UTC)) AS EventPayload#97]
   +- Project [EventPayload#13]
      +- Filter (EventPayloadType#11 = AccountCreatedEvent)
         +- Relation [Id#2L,EventId#3,EnvelopeVersion#4,Domain#5,EventSource#6,EventProducerId#7,ClientRequestId#8,CorrelationId#9,EventTimestamp#10,EventPayloadType#11,EventPayloadVersion#12,EventPayload#13,Created#14] JDBCRelation(Money.Events) [numPartitions=1]
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Better fit for StackOverFlow.

Comment: Is this pyspark?